# xspec: error while loading shared libraries: libXSPlot.so: cannot open shared object file: no such directory

Tags: ubuntu, xspec

I have this error message when trying to launch xspec on the virtual machine with ubuntu os.

I found its location via

```
locate libXSPlot.so
```

```
/home/studente/heasoft-6.28/Xspec/BLD/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/lib/libXSPlot.so
/home/studente/heasoft-6.28/Xspec/src/XSPlot/libXSPlot.so
/home/studente/heasoft-6.28/Xspec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/lib/libXSPlot.so
/home/studente/heasoft-6.28/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/lib/libXSPlot.so
```

I have tried

```
sudo ln -s /home/studente/heasoft-6.28/Xspec/BLD/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/lib/libXSPlot.so
```

and got

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link './libXSPlot.so': File exists
```

Another try was

```
sudo apt install apt-file libXSPlot.so
```

Here is what I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libXSPlot.so
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libXSPlot.so'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXSPlot.so'
```

Please, help me to link these libraries

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in heasoft-6.29 built from source on Ubuntu.

In my case, the solution was that  $LD_LIBRAY_PATH was reset by another software. To solve the problem, I had to comment out the line in the setup of that software where this environmental variable was set, and now XSPEC can find the XSPlot library
(which, as you noticed, was part of the original installation of XSPEC)